# Regex Pattern for multiple elements in XSD

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

Is it possible to check different regex pattern for many elements. For Example:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" > 

  <xsd:element name="A" type="emailAddress"/> 
  <xsd:element name="B" type="Name"/> 
  <xsd:element name="C" type="Age"/> 
  <xsd:element name="D" type="Number"/> 

  <xsd:simpleType name="emailAddress"> 
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"> 
      <xsd:pattern value="[^@]+@[^\.]+\..+"/> 
    </xsd:restriction> 
  </xsd:simpleType> 
</xsd:schema>
```

In the above XSD i have only 4 elements and i have provided a regex pattern for element A . But my case is that i have 50 elements each having different regex pattern. How can i provide regex for all those 50 elements because defining regex as above is too big. Please let me know if there are any way of providing for elements?

Comment: You need to add a `<xsl:simpleType>` for each element.

Comment: If you have 50 different types, each requiring a different regex, in what way are you looking to improve upon separate simple type declarations for each type?  Is it merely the verbosity of the `simpleType-restrictions-pattern` construction that you seek to minimize, or is it something more than that?

Comment: Creating <xsd:simpleType> and providing restriction for all 50 elements is too complex. Is there any other alternative way of providing pattern in a simple way

Comment: See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42724322/290085) for options.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i provide regex for all those 50 elements because defining
>   regex as above is too big.

Options:

1. Use local type declarations rather than references to named global
   declarations.
2. Use constructs other than `xsd:pattern` regex.  (Do you really want
   to use regex for numeric types, for example?)
3. Group types into common categories, possibly arranged hierarchically.  (Are all 50 types truly orthogonal?)
4. Bite the bullet and define 50 distinct, named, global types.
5. Punt and make them all unrestricted strings or `anyType`.

Comment: Could you please provide an example.

Comment: Of which option?  Your question is rather broad and abstract, so  I've  answered accordingly.  You'll need to chose one of the options if you want more details.

Comment: Given the vague and incomplete description of the problem, I recommend #2 or #3 if possible; #4 otherwise.  I would have to invent more detail than you've provided in your question to give you examples, and I'm not going to do that -- that's your job.